# How to enter factory mode on Insyde bios (acer)

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, uefi, acer

I was disassembling an Acer Helios 300 317-52 and noticed after it sat for a long time with the CMOS, battery, and a module labeled "vendor" being unplugged from the motherboard, it would only boot to a black screen, then shut off. I tried going into the UEFI firmware and there it was, a red UEFI firmware with *Factory Setup* displayed (or something like that), with a lot of options.

- Is there any way this can be reproduced, as I couldn't get it to work?
- Does this exist anywhere or is it documented, as it seems weird something like that exists?

The UEFI firmware is original never changed/updated

Comment: All boards have a factory mode so they can be programmed by the OEM with non-changeable info such as a service tag/equivalent, but it's unusual for an end user to stumble upon it accdientally since laptop OEMs heavily lock down their BIOS and UEFI firmwares _(it used to be possible to unlock BIOS images to gain access to the myriad of additional options end users are locked out of, but that stopped being possible with UEFI since the firmware must be digitally signed and verified to even enter flashing mode)_

Comment: Is this fixed by installing back the "Vendor" module?

Comment: @harrymc I am unable to replicate this, that's what I wanted to ask, since it was very unusual. But the entire device seems to be pre-production as the serial is in fact not found and it was a display only model. There was also a lot of the factory tapes etc. not applied inside. I will try to reproduce this but it's very very weird.